# Jquery .html() replacing everything

Tags: jquery

I want to replace an element's content with different content in a html string. Im getting the element via a HTML5 data attribute. The backbone template returns html_string, a long string of divs and nested divs.

```
var html_string = template({model:player});

var newHtml = $(html_string).find("[data-position='Forward_1']").html("<div>NEWCONTENT</div>").html();

console.log('new html is');
console.log(newHtml);
```

The output is:

```
new html is 
<div>NEW CONTENT</div>
```

So everything is getting replaced..

Comment: What is `html` in your selector?

Comment: What is `template` and what does it return? ... and so on :) Basically what we're getting at is that you need to either pass a HTML string, a valid selector, or a valid DOM element into the `$()` method to be able to call `.find` on it

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to find all `[data-position='Forward_1']` elements, you don't need .find:

```
$("[data-position='Forward_1']").html("<div>NEW CONTENT</div>");
```

edit:

Since you are actually manipulating a HTML string with this:

```
$("<div> ... </div>").find("[data-position='Forward_1']").html("<div>NEW CONTENT</div>");
```

You need to do *something* with the resulting element. Either add it to the DOM:

```
$("body").append($(html).find("[data-position='Forward_1']").html("<div>NEW CONTENT</div>"));
```

Or get the resulting HTML:

```
var newHtml = $(html).find("[data-position='Forward_1']").html("<div>NEW CONTENT</div>").html()
```

Comment: I edited the question. the html variable is not actually in the DOM, its a string of html...So i need to use the .find() on it I think

Comment: sorry, i edited the question. its practically a different question, maybe i should delete and start a new one